# Download python library from Github "requires a different Python"

Tags: python, github

I'm trying to download python library from github, by using this comand in cmd: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall https://github.com/BurnySc2/python-sc2/archive/develop.zip`
But in the end, I catch an error:

[image]

> ERROR: Package 'burnysc2' requires a different Python: 3.10.2 not in
> '<3.10,>=3.7'

I have the latest version of Python (3.10.2)
Is there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That library [doesn't officially support Python 3.10](https://github.com/BurnySc2/python-sc2/blob/b595bbe1a5b252f49fb60592742d2750c5fc6df6/pyproject.toml#L33), as the error message says.

> I have the latest version of Python (3.10.2) Is there any ways to solve this problem?

I believe you can try adding [`--python-version 3.9`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-python-version) to your command. This should let you install with Python 3.10 even though it isn't officially supported:

> The Python interpreter version to use for wheel and “Requires-Python” compatibility checks. Defaults to a version derived from the running interpreter.

If this works and all tests pass, consider changing the version constraint to include Python 3.10 and submitting a pull request.

Or you could downgrade to Python 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

try download the wheel file and force install it using
`pip install <package-name> --ignore-requires-python --target <directory>`
but it probably won't work